# Flex layout column height

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.flex-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-body div{
  width: 50%;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-body">
  <div style="background: #0980cc; height:100px;"></div>
  <div style="background: #09cc69;height: 200px;"></div>
  <div style="background: #cc092f;height:170px;"></div>
  <div style="background: #0980cc; height:130px;"></div>
  <div style="background: #09cc69;height: 100px;"></div>
  <div style="background: yellow;height: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

I want to fill the white space between rows in flex container, each element has a different height and I want the element to be stacked on top of each other directly

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgar4ebt/8/)

Comment: I think it is not clear enough what you want to achieve to answer your question. Could you please elaborate more the intended layout and the difference to the present layout?

Comment: @LarsGendner If you can see the white space below the first blue element

Comment: well it's always hard for me to find this duplicate :) i sould make it as favorite next time i find it ... but @LGson  will close it when he comes ;)

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly, but what you want is a Massonry grid with flexbox?

Comment: I don't think its possible with `flexbox`...

Comment: With flexbox you can play with max-height and `flex-direction: column` [example](https://jsfiddle.net/13g3hojm/5/)

Answer (score -1):

The blank spaces only exist because you set the height of each Flex child. Just don't, and they'll naturally fill the space.

```css
.flex-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width : 100vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

.flex-body div{
  flex-basis : 50%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  outline: blue dashed 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-body">
  <div style="background: #0980cc;"></div>
  <div style="background: #09cc69;"></div>
  <div style="background: #cc092f;"></div>
  <div style="background: #0980cc;"></div>
  <div style="background: #09cc69;"></div>
  <div style="background: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if they have different heights?

Comment: But you said `I want to fill the white space between rows`, so you want elements with different heights, but with the same height? Wut?

Comment: @JeremyThille OP does not want space between 1st and 3rd div with different height....